# JSON nested array for Geolocation

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to take a JSON feed and use the information to plot shuttle buses on google maps.  I can't seem to figure out how to remove the header.  Or maybe I don't even have to and I'm missing something.  The JSON feed looks like this:

```
{"header":{"gtfs_realtime_version":"1","incrementality":0,"timestamp":1473346401},"entity":[{"id":"1","is_deleted":false,"trip_update":null,"vehicle":{"trip":{"trip_id":"2351087","start_time":"10:30:00","start_date":"20160908","schedule_relationship":0,"route_id":"30"},"position":{"latitude":41.7992477,"longitude":-71.44529,"bearing":360.0,"odometer":0.0,"speed":0.0},"current_stop_sequence":0,"current_status":2,"timestamp":1473346346,"congestion_level":0,"stop_id":"12815","vehicle":{"id":"1604","label":"1604","license_plate":" "}},"alert":null},{"id":"2","is_deleted":false,"trip_update":null,
```

The above goes on for about 20 more shuttles.

Below is what I have for the function.  I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined".  I can't figure out how to get rid of the header although there could be more errors.  I'm not much of a programmer, I'm learning as I go. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
placeVehicles1();
setInterval(placeVehicles1, 15000);

function placeVehicles1() {

$.getJSON('JSON URL', function(datah){  
$.each(datah, function(key){

var hillArray =[key] ;

hillArray[0] =datah['entity']['vehicle'][key]['190'];
hillArray[1] =datah['entity']['vehicle'][key]['191'];
hillArray[2] =datah['entity']['vehicle'][key]['192'];

    var number = hillArray[key]; 
    for(h=0; h<101; h++){
    {
            var Latitudeh = datah['position'][key]['latitude'];
            var Longitudeh = datah['position'][key]['logitude'];
            var Timeh = datah['entity'][key].timestamp;
            var Routeh = datah[key].Route_id;
            var Vehicleh = datah[key].Vehicle;
            //markersArray.length=0;
            markersArray.push(datah);

            //Set Lat and Long of each Bus

            var imageh = 'GoldBus.png';
            var myLatlngh = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(datah['position'][key]['latitude']),parseFloat(datah['position'][key]['logitude']));
if (h=101){
marker=null;
}else{}
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlngh,
                title: 'Shuttle',
                map: map,
                icon: imageh
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
        //}}
        // Define Content to Show in popup
            var mycontenth = "<div class='infowin'>Time:<h3>" + Timeh + "</h3>" + "Route:<h3>" + Routeh + "</h3>" + "Vehicle:<h3>" + Vehicleh + "</h3></div>";
            var infowindowh = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: mycontenth         
});
```

Comment: What line is your error pointing you to? Could you include that line (and the relevant nearby lines of code)? Your error is telling you that you've passed an undefined object to your function somewhere. It's trying to read the "header" key of the undefined object (which doesn't exist). Your problem isn't that you need to get rid of header, your problem is that it isn't there when it's expected.

Comment: somewhere in your code there is a 'lalal.header' where lalal is undefined.  If you can show around there we can probably help you out.  I'm guessing an error with asynch.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm new to stackoverflow also.  The error I am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined" on the line of code "hillArray[0] =datah['entity']['vehicle'][key]['190'];"

Comment: @Shaun, no worries. Thx for including the line. Try `hillArray[0] = datah['entity']['vehicle'] ? datah['entity']['vehicle'][key]['190'] : ""` Do the same with hillArray[1] and hillArray[2]

Comment: Thank you Adam.  I no longer get any errors on the hillArray lines.  I was getting an error on: var Latitudeh = datah['position'][key]['latitude']; but I changed that code to: var Latitudeh = datah[key]['latitude']; and similiar for the lines below it.  I no longer get any errors however it also does not plot any of the buses.